# How are global cloud cover estimates generated and how is the data accessed?

Tags: meteorology, measurements, clouds, open-data

The website [ventusky.com](https://www.ventusky.com/?p=20.31;-155.35;6&l=clouds) offers three models to produce cloud estimate: [ICON](https://www.mpimet.mpg.de/en/science/models/icon/), [GFS](http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/products/gfs/) and [GEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Environmental_Multiscale_Model). They extract a fractional cloud number, shown in percentage.

From the [ERDDAP portal](http://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/NCEP_Global_Best.html) to the GFS model (NCEP_Global_Best), the only relevant data regarding clouds is:

- dlwrfsfc (net downward longwave radiation flux, $Wm^{-2}$)
- dswrfsfc (net downward shortwave radiation flux, $Wm^{-2}$)

Is there a way to estimate fractional cloud coverage from these two parameters or does GFS offer some other product for global cloud coverage?

Is there a GRIB or other type of portal with an API to access cloud coverage estimates?

---

Edit:  I tried openDap as suggested, but the help pages are not clear.  And I don't understand the ranges on the time specifications. Let's say I want to look at 22N, 155W (just 1 point) and look at a 24-hour time frame. I tried [this](https://rda.ucar.edu/thredds/dodsC/aggregations/g/ds084.1/1/ds084.1-2017/TwoD?lat[88:1:88],lon[820:1:820],time[301950:1:301970],Total_cloud_cover_entire_atmosphere_Mixed_intervals_Average[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0]).

Lat 88, lon 820, time 301950-301970 (I just assumed, probably incorrectly that it ends at the current offset from  2015-01-15T00:00:00Z).  But the results are not what I would expect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://journals.co-action.net/index.php/tellusa/article/viewFile/15648/17540 . This paper may help at least give an idea on what the problem is

Comment: And regarding getting GFS data of cloud coverage if you know OPeNDAP just go over here and search for cloud_cover - https://rda.ucar.edu/thredds/dodsC/aggregations/g/ds084.1/1/ds084.1-2017/TwoD.html

Comment: @gansub that something is on topic elsewhere on the internet does not make it off topic here.

Comment: @SimonW - I am sorry if you read that as the "internet". I meant elsewhere on StackExchange such as OpenData.SE.

Comment: @gansub that something is on topic elsewhere in Stackexchange does not make it off topic here ;-)

More seriously, I would argue that while providing detailed support on OpenDAP in a way that was not earth science specific would be off-topic here, simply suggesting that OpenDAP might be a solution to an earth science problem is not.

Comment: @SimonW - so what did I say that was wrong ? I am not getting it actually. OP asked for data  source for cloud cover and I gave it to him. If he asked for how to download data using OPeNDAP that would have to be a separate question. He went ahead and modified his original question to make it -show me how to download data using OPeNDAP

Comment: @gansub This forum seemed a little slow, so I thought it would be ok to discuss the mechanics of how to access the data which was part of my original question.  While OpenData might help with the technical bits I think there are weather specific questions about what OPeNDAP settings and results are.

Comment: @gansub ah, apologies - I hadn't spotted the sequence of edits. I still probably wouldn't complain about off-topicness in this case, but I'm not any sort of authority :-)

Comment: @user6972 - are you comfortable programming in python ? If so forget the technical nuances of OPeNDAP and just use Siphon - https://unidata.github.io/siphon/ and that will help you download GFS data in a netCDF format